# Getting result from HList by path dependent type

Tags: scala, shapeless

I am trying to learn shapeless. I have a toy project, but I faced with a problem.

```
sealed trait RunnerType
object RunnerType {
  case object BasicRunner extends RunnerType
  case object MidComplex extends RunnerType
  case object ComplexRunner extends RunnerType
}
trait Runner[Input, Output] {
  type T
  def inner: Input => Output
  def apply(in: Input): Output = inner(in)
} 
object Runner { 
  case class A(inner: Int => String) extends Runner[Int, String] {
    type T = RunnerType.BasicRunner.type
  }  
  case class B(inner: Any => Any) extends Runner[Any, Any] {
    type T = RunnerType.MidComplex.type
  } 
  case class C(inner: String => (Int => String)) extends Runner[String, (Int => String)] {
    type T = RunnerType.BasicRunner.type
  } 
  //DSL
  def a(f: Int => String) = A(f) 
  def b(f: Any => Any) = B(f) 
  def c(f: String => (Int => String)) = C(f)
 // ops...
  val list = List(
    a(i => i.toString), 
    c(i => a => i.toString + (a + 10).toString)
    , b(a => a)
  )      
}
```

As you can see, my dsl is not proper for usage, because I lost completely type, and I want to search by RunnerType. If I use HList, probably I can keep type information. Such as"

```
  val hlist = 
    a(i => i.toString) ::: c(i => a => i.toString + (a + 10).toString) ::: b(a => a) ::: HNil
```

Now I want to have a method, that takes RunnerType as a parameter, and returns the correct object that I can use apply method and know input and output type. For example:

```
  def lookup[L <: HList](t:RunnerType, hlist: L): Runner[correct_input, correct_output] = // Lookup in hlist for t(runner type)
```

Is it the correct usage of Hlist? If it is, how I can reach this with shapeess?

Comment: Why do you want to represent your DSL as a list/HList instead of a coproduct? If there is more than one instance of `A` in the same HList, what do you expect `lookup` to get?

Comment: Because it will be recursive DSL. And I am planning to prevent duplicate instances. However, what do you actually mean by coproduct representation for this case?

Comment: I guess you want to choose to run A or B or C? so in my opinion, it's more like a coproduct (or) relationship rather than a list/product (and) relationship. If it must be a HList, you may create a `Aux[RT] = Runner { type T = RT }` type to bind T inside Runner, then use `select` to find the right Runner.